# How can achieve this UI for flutter using stack or any other equivalent option

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to implement this UI with flutter, but using container i cannot get a perfect half circle or whatever it is called in my design.

Desired Output:

[image]

Current Output:

[image]

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smarthomeapp/colors.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: AppColors.containerColor,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have used stack widget, but the container width doesn't exceed the app screen.

Comment: You won't be able to do it using containers and modifying their radii. You will need to make it using custom paints. One possible way of achieving it is by first drawing a rectangle with rounded bottoms and then drawing a curve that runs from top left to the top right and then filling this entire path with a paint

Comment: i mean you could stack different materials, with different shapes (background rectangle and 2 circles), see [Material.shape](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material/shape.html). But at least for the little arrow on the second circle, i would also suggest custom paints. Especially when it should be animated.